# Hide and show multiple divs onclick jQuery - WordPress

Tags: jquery

With jQuery I want to hide and show multiple divs onclick. I have written some code, but it is not working.

My JavaScript only works when I set all the divs at a new line. But I would like to select multiple divs at once so the code will be shorter. I tried using document.querySelectorAll to select multiple divs at once. But that also didn't do the trick. So now I'm trying jQuery.

This is my code so far. But it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#fm-button").click(function(){
    $("#first-image, #subtitle, #content").show();
    $("#content-1, #content-2, #subtitle-1, #subtitle-2, #second-image, #third-image").hide();
  });
});
```

Here is the HTML. I am using PHP also.

```
<?php if(get_sub_field('FM_button_text') ) : ?>
    <div class="FM-button" id="fm-button" onclick="screenChangeFm()">
        <img class="FM-card-image" src="<?php the_sub_field('FM_image'); ?>" alt="feedmanagement_image">
        <p class="card-text"><span><?php the_sub_field("FM_button_text"); ?></span></p>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<h2 class="sub" id="subtitle">Some Text 0</h2>
<h2 class="sub" id="subtitle-1" style="display: none">Some Text 1</h2>
<h2 class="sub" id="subtitle-2" style="display: none">Some Text 2</h2>

<img id="first-image" src="<?php the_sub_field('image-1'); ?>"alt="helpcenter_image">
<img id="second-image" src="<?php the_sub_field('image-2'); ?>" alt="helpcenter_image" style="display: none">
<img id="third-image" src="<?php the_sub_field('image-3'); ?>" alt="helpcenter_image" style="display: none">

<p id="content"><?php the_sub_field('content'); ?></p>
<p id="content-1" style="display: none">Subtext!</p>
<p id="content-2" style="display: none">Subtext! $#2</p>

I expect that when I click on #fm-button, some divs will hide and other will show.
```

Comment: Your JS code seems fine in isolation. Can you please also add your HTML to the question

Comment: N.B. your two code snippets do not actually provide precisely the same functionality...the second one is lacking the `if` logic. But in principle it at least should do something...even if it's not precisely what you expect. As Rory says, show the related HTML then we can actually test it out.

Comment: I guess it's a matter of preference but I wouldn't mix vanilla js with jQuery.

Comment: I agree Tcj. I am trying both because I want to most clean/short code. The JavaScript code is working for me, but I want it cleaner, so I'm trying jQuery now.

Comment: I thought they were two different functions, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another way of add a listener to an HTML object.

```
$(document).on('click',"#fm-button",function(event){
    $("#first-image, #subtitle, #content").show();
    $("#content-1, #content-2, #subtitle-1, #subtitle-2, #second-image, #third-image").hide();
});
```

Tell me if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have tried the code but neither the show or hide works.

Comment: @LauraV6 can you check if jquery is well imported? You can use this script: ```<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>```

Answer (score 0):

@wasanga7 I am using WordPress, and instead of $ I needed to use jQuery.
The code works now!

```
jQuery(document).on('click',"#fm-button",function(event){
    jQuery("#first-image, #subtitle, #content").show();
    jQuery("#content-1, #content-2, #subtitle-1, #subtitle-2, #second-image, #third-image").hide();
});
```

Comment: I'm glad for you!